# How do i Recompile php on ubuntu?

Tags: php, gd

I am getting this error

```
Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()
```

and after reading around i need to recompile php with

```
- ./configure --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib OR any other directory which contains the BINARY library of libjpeg
```

but what directory and is there a module that i need to enable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: @Jonah: what do you propose then? `reload` it? Not a big difference on development server.

Comment: I'd propose nothing.  Apache must only be restarted when something having to do with it is changed.  PHP is independent, and called every time a page is loaded.

Comment: @Jonah: if php set up as an **apache module**, then your thoughts are just wrong.

Comment: I suppose you could put that in in case it is.  I assumed it was installed separately.

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
sudo apt get install php5-gd
```

This will not recompile PHP, but will add GD support, that is the extension you need.

```
sudo apache2ctl graceful
```

May be needed to activate it

Answer (score 3):

The default `/usr/lib` is the correct value for finding `libjpeg.so.62` on Debian/Ubuntu.

Your problem is more likely that you haven't installed the header files, so PHP and the GD extension autoconfig script cannot find it. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev libjpeg62
```